# Add file to document library, title not getting updated

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, ssom

```
var htable = new HashTable();
    htable.Add("Title", "Value1");
    htable.Add("OtherField", "Value");
    
    web.Files.add(fileName, buffer, htable, true);
```

This should be creating the file and putting the specified value in the Title...however, it's not updating the title column no matter what (but it works for the other columns). In addition, the destination library is newly created so it doesn't have any specific configuration.

PS: Updating the item in a second step is not the preferred solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post appears to answer your question: [Set Title Field on Document Upload](http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2014/03/21/set-title-field-document-upload/)

[image: Blog screen capture]